# Change drawable start color and end color dynamically in android activity class

Tags: android, background, drawable

Hi I am developing one android application in which I drawable resource to set backgroung for button. I want to change start and end color for that drawable programatically i.e. in activity class inside button click listener. My drawable looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient android:startColor="#be584c" 
    android:endColor="#be584c"
    android:angle="270" />
  <corners android:radius="2dp" />
  <stroke android:width="1px"/>
</shape>
```

And I set it as background for button in xml file. `android:background="@drawable/download_button"`

and i want to change start color and end color of this drawable in activity class how to do this. Is there any way to f=do this. Need help. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You should use **GradientDrawable** to do this.

```
int colors[] = { 0xff255779, 0xffa6c0cd };

GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
        GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors);

view.setBackgroundDrawable(gradientDrawable);
```

Change color code as per your requirement. Though I used `Color.parseColor("color code")`, its not working.

There are some option for **Orientation** like following.

```
GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP;
GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT;
GradientDrawable.Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT;
```

Answer (score 2):

Chintan's solution is good enough if you don't mind to create the `GradientDrawable` again, but if you just want to **change** the colors without touching other attributes like padding etc, you can simply use `setColors`. In the following case it shows how to change `startColor`, `centerColor`, and `endColor`.

```
int color = screenshot.getPixel(x, y);
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)binding.layoutStation.getBackground();
int colors[] = { color, 0xffffffff, color };
drawable.setColors(colors);
```

Answer (score -1):

new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TL_BR, new int[]{0xFF141a24, 0xFF293f49, 0xFF72554c})