# How can changes Change drawable gradient start color and end color dynamically with "android:state_pressed" in android activity

Tags: android, gradient, android-xml

I have three XML file. First, two is I am applying some gradient start color , end color, and the third one is I am checking pressed status (true or false for changing Bg). how can I change my first two XML  gradient start color ,end color dynamically ( 1.blue_rounded_bg and 2.gray_rounded_bg) and that dynamic start color and end color is reflected my third file(pressed status checking- 3, blue_btn)?

First XML file: Blue color Bg (file name: blue_rounded_bg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/size25"
    android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/size25"
    android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/size25"
    android:topRightRadius="@dimen/size25" />
<padding
    android:bottom="@dimen/size5"
    android:left="@dimen/size5"
    android:right="@dimen/size5"
    android:top="@dimen/size5" />

<solid android:color="@color/btn_gray" />
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:startColor="@color/btn_blue"
    android:endColor="@color/btn_light_blue"
    android:type="linear" />
```

Second XML file: Gray color Bg (file name: gray_rounded_bg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/size25"
    android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/size25"
    android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/size25"
    android:topRightRadius="@dimen/size25" />
<padding
    android:bottom="@dimen/size5"
    android:left="@dimen/size5"
    android:right="@dimen/size5"
    android:top="@dimen/size5" />

<solid android:color="@color/btn_gray" />
```

Third XML file:  I am checking pressed status using below code (File name: blue_btn )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_rounded_bg" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_rounded_bg" android:state_enabled="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_rounded_bg" />
```

My normal XML code

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/cont_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_btn"
        android:padding="@dimen/size6" />
```

Then, How can I change drawable gradient start color ,end color dynamically and that changes reflected in

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_rounded_bg" android:state_pressed="true" />
```

This file also ? its possible or not?

[image: XML file one shows like that-Blue color]
[image: XML file two shows like that-Gray color]

Answer (score 2):

Try this, use GradientDrawable to do this.

```
int colors[] = { 0xff255779, 0xffa6c0cd };

GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
        GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors);

view.setBackgroundDrawable(gradientDrawable);
```

Change color code as per your requirement. Though I used Color.parseColor("color code"), its not working.

There are some option for Orientation like following.

```
GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP;
GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT;
GradientDrawable.Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT;
```

Comment: I am using the custom shape

Comment: could you refer my sample images. i am asking how can i change start color and end color at dynamically.

Comment: <item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_rounded_bg" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_rounded_bg" android:state_enabled="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_rounded_bg" />

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650488/change-drawable-start-color-and-end-color-dynamically-in-android-activity-class?rq=1

Comment: Did you copy from above link right ? plz, read my question clearly

Comment: your case is possible you should try my answer in your java code

Comment: yes its working for me also that's i copy the code with you

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/cont_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_btn"
        android:padding="@dimen/size6" />

Comment: are you undrstand clearly my question?  plz you change my first two XML gradient start color ,end color dynamically  and that dynamic start color and end color is reflected me third file ( 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_rounded_bg" android:state_pressed="true" /> <item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_rounded_bg" android:state_enabled="false" /> <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_rounded_bg" />)